# CloudConvert API import/upload task always marked as "Waiting for Upload"

Tags: python, cloudconvert

This is my first time using the CloudConvert API, and I attempting to perform HTML to PDF file conversion. I have read/followed the official documentation as well used the provided "Job Builder," but no matter what I try, the import/upload task is always stuck as "Waiting for Upload".

Of course, I didn't expect the program to work on the first try, but the file won't upload; there aren't any errors either. The file I'm attempting to upload is main.html, which is in the same directory as my Python file. Here is my code:

```
cloudconvert.configure(api_key='API_KEY', sandbox=False)
job = cloudconvert.Job.create(payload={
    "tasks": {
        "import-file": {
            "operation": "import/upload",
            "input": "upload",
            "file": "main.html"
        },
        "convert-pdf": {
            "operation": "convert",
            "input_format": "html",
            "output_format": "pdf",
            "engine": "chrome",
            "input": [
                "import-file"
            ],
            "zoom": 1,
            "print_background": True,
            "display_header_footer": False,
            "wait_until": "load",
            "wait_time": 0,
            "filename": "main.pdf"
        },
        "output-schedule": {
            "operation": "export/url",
            "input": [
                "convert-pdf"
            ],
            "inline": False,
            "archive_multiple_files": False
        }
    },
    "tag": "jobbuilder"
})
```

I know there was an issue a few years ago on CloudConvert's end that caused all uploaded files to be marked as "waiting." Is there something wrong with my code, or could it be a repeat of that situation?